Wordpress - Page is automatically redirecting
I have this url: https://example.com/kena-bridge-of-spirits/redeem/
Someone asked if I could shorten it to this: https://example.com/kena/redeem/
That's fine, but I found that before I even did anything, the second url redirected to the first one. I don't have any hard coded redirects set up or plugins that would cause a redirect. I also did various searches in the database and came up with nothing.
Can someone explain why this is happening? Why wouldn't it just result in a 404?

Do you have something like this installed?

@Cam I don't. The only thing remotely close to url handling would be SEO Framework and all I've done there was adjust some basic schema markup settings

If it's not a plugin feature it could also be a theme feature.

I checked the second link. It is a 404 page.
